# monaco-editor how to hide lightbulb in diff editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

[image]

[demo](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.36.1#XQAAAALJAgAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw2X-9ZzFWtoIlelWaKUmXaJ2qI2Mq9sv8BEYnm73B8SrDwdJv_xsq1lMQKOQ7NxRMghUI-L8fGKpfa_kdVD53Elu5zsstd-LrcZnCAekL7Xszw_0boyJl8EvkkveoIprSYJOb3ZNrtfCFKAuZmGk6xwyxQF84t-XE18YyBidH-AECqIkBlP5kktJLoulc_ANjvBbu8uQN_pRCPWiVMDgtSv6g2XcdEGrnj5Yspjl-5EtNr1tsxVpwUBdgI5MMiRqvE-EWVyVQeaSz60z3kHIpC5BCFbHBY42k3xcattwwozhXJ0lUM3ojCGleNENzKZy6pvZSDBofq3aCmz7i-hj7nvIuXFygIrL-wpziCKOrWDWMC8C1SeM-TMQEvy3Or2ZheKYlkWe2vavF9AuzE5W3q5dbcMJ4gSXfJfSs39SMLjUBVhfDzPzcYfsYUd6BCX__yx_5Cg)

How to hide lightbulb in monaco-editor diff editor?

`lightbulb: {enabled: false }` is not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems that if `renderSideBySide` is false, then lightbulb will be shown. I created an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/3873) in monaco-editor.

For now, you can remove lightbulb by setting `renderSideBySide: false`